# Do theravada buddhists not think that the mahayana is buddhism?

Tags: discussion

It seems like some don't.

I do think that those who don't should be made not to post "no Buddhist says" etc., as it is highly misleading for a site which is meant to explore questions and answers on this topic

Comment: arguments from the 1st century without context :(

Answer (score 1):

**It seems like some don't.**

Maybe it does seem like that.

Perhaps the title goes too far, I don't think I'd assume that all Theravada Buddhists do or don't think something based on what one or two people say.

Even so there may be some truth in it, see e.g. [this interchange](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/if-a-buddhist-should-not-kill-a-mouse-living-in-their-home-what-justification-d/10766#comment16597_10766) (in which Sankha is Theravada and Andrei Mahayana):

> - Theravada Buddhists don't really recognize other schools. Mostly historians do that. So it's just Buddhism for us. – Sankha Kulathantille
> - And we do recognize other schools, it's all Buddhism for us :) – Andrei Volkov♦

**I do think that those who don't should be made not to post "no Buddhist says" etc.**

If that's their considered opinion there may be a limit to how much we should "make them" not do it.

Let's assume, for the sake of argument, that some Buddhists *do* believe something:

- As moderator, I'm inclined to draw the *do-not-cross-this-line* line at hostility: if a statement seems hostile or even mis-read as hostile, "no Buddhist says, anyone who says that can't be a Buddhist, and furthermore they shouldn't be allowed to post here", then I might say something.
- However, and maybe more likely, perhaps the statement is some unawareness (of other schools). If it's not hostile it's not my business to correct every misconception in every answer.

As a user, if *you* find an answer "highly misleading" then you can post a comment to contradict, e.g., "Actually, the such-and-such school *does* say that." I hope that if you do your comment should be friendly, intended to avoid misleading readers and/or to inform the OP, trying to add to their answer rather than to take away from it, not to start some kind of sectarian argument about who might be right or wrong.

There have been many discussions here on Meta over this kind of topic -- for example I recommend:

- [Overt Sectarian Affiliations](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1660/254)
- [Sectarian shout downs should be dealt with](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100/254)
- [Theravada and Mahayana](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13/254)
- [How to ask questions about different traditions of Buddhism?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1508/254)
- [May people criticize other schools of Buddhism?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/254)
- [Are we here to preach and make converts?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/254)

I also encourage you to 'flag' any post or comment which seems to you hostile. A flags can be helpful, because moderators don't necessarily read or notice everything?